# How to download zip file created from jszip.js in IE9 and lower version without using flash based downlodify

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I don’t want to use flash based downlodify for downloading zip file created from jszip.

I am fine to use ActiveX, therefore I am trying to convert jszip to ActiveX.

The zip file is getting generated but it’s is not valid file. What is wrong with my below conversion for IE9?

This if for IE9 –

```
var content = zip.generate({ type: "base64" });
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var a = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\Temp\test.zip", true);
a.WriteLine(content);
a.Close();
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "C:\Temp\test.zip";
link.style = "visibility:hidden";
link.download = "test.zip";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

For other browsers I am happily using the below code.

```
var content = zip.generate({ type: "blob" });
saveAs(content, "test.zip");
```

Need help for IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175259/using-createobjecturl-to-create-a-downloadable-json-file-works-in-mobiledeskt):

```
var a, blob, data, downloadLink, json, url;

data  = {whatever: 1};

json = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = "test.json";
a.href = url;
a.textContent = "Download";

document.getElementById("link").appendChild(a);
```

Here the user creates a `blob` object, then creates an URL for that blob and creates an anchor that links to the URL.

Comment: Blob is not supported by IE9

Answer (score 0):

`Scripting.FileSystemObject` seems to handle text files, not binary files. What you want is a way to write a *binary* file.

I found http://www.neilstuff.com/save-binary-file-to-disk-in-javascript.html which could help you. I tried it in IE9 but I couldn't get past the security errors (I'm writing arbitrary files on the disk after all).

Also, don't forget to change the type into "string" : `zip.generate({type:"string"})`.

Comment: new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream"); is not supported by IE9.